# Add attachment to an existing email

Tags: vba, outlook

The code below adds an attachment, however it creates a new email.

```
Sub BA7()
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments
    myAttachments.Add "J:\BUILDING\Email attachments\BA7word.docx", _
    olByValue, 1, "BA7"
End Sub
```

Is there a way to add an attachment to the currently open email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the line

```
Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
```

with

```
Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
```

if the item is opened in an inspector or with the following if it is selected in the Explorer message list:

```
Set myItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
```